# ASP.NET Web API OAuth2 customize 401 unauthorized response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.  My resource server is configured as follows:

```
// Resource server configuration
var audience = "hello";
var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode("world);

// Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
    new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
        AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
        IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
        {
            new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
        }
    });
```

Currently, when a token is expired, the Reponse is as follows:

```
401 Unauthorized
**Headers:**
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Www-Authenticate: Bearer
X-Sourcefiles: =?UTF-8?B?Yzpcc3JjXFVTQi5FbnRlcnByaXNlQXV0b21hdGlvbi5BdXRoQXBpXFVTQi5FbnRlcnByaXNlQXV0b21hdGlvbi5BdXRoQXBpXGFwaVx1c2VyXGxvb2t1cFxsaWtvc3Rv?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 30 Dec 2016 13:54:26 GMT
Content-Length: 61
```

Body

```
{
"message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."
}
```

Is there a way to set a custom Www-Authenticate header, and/or add to the body if the token is expired?

I'd like to return something like:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example", 
    error="invalid_token", 
    error_description="The access token expired"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` and then decorate the method or class in question. Make sure to override `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` and then call its `base` method to carry on as normal and return `401`.

```
public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("WWW-Authenticate", @"Bearer realm=""example"" ... ");
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(actionContext);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CustomAuthorize]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    ...
}
```

May need some further logic around headers but should be enough to get started with.